# Replacing string in column headers Python with a string from an array

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying to replace a certain string in my column headers with  a new string that includes a part from an array. (Otherwise my columns have duplicated column headers that aren't useful)

However I am having difficulty with my datatype when adding my new name to a list and then changing the column headers to the new list of names. Why isn't the new names looking like a list rather than a list of 1x1 arrays? Thanks

```
states = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
i=0
    new_names = []
    for name in df_state_arrears.columns:
        if '30+ Arrears %' in name:
            name = '30+ Arrears %' + ' '+ states[i]
            i=i+1
        new_names.append([name]) 

df.columns = new_names  

Length mismatch: Expected axis has 16 elements, new values have 1 elements
```

Comment: I think you just need to use `new_names.append(name)` so that `new_names` is a list of strings instead of a list of lists.

Comment: thank you! I knew it was something simple! I thought I had already tried that and got some list error but must have been something else. Cheers